# The asynchronous operation has already completed

Tags: vb.net, service-broker, asynchronous

I have a VB.net app with a DataGridView displaying a list of jobs, retrieved from a SQL query into a DataTable, then a DataView and finally a BindingSource for the DataGridView.DataSource.  I have recently added SqlNotificationRequest functionality to the setup so user A is immediately updated when user B performs an action on a job in the list.

I used this MSDN article ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3ht3391b(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3ht3391b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) as the basis for my development and it works ok.  The problem comes when the user wants to change the parameters of the SQL query which displays the jobs, for example the date displayed.  Currently I am creating a new SqlCommand with new Notification but after the user has changed the date a few times (say 30), but no data changes, when the notification timeout occurs I receive the above error when the callback handler tried to EndExecuteReader.  My callback handler is below:

```
    Private Sub OnSalesReaderComplete(ByVal asynResult As IAsyncResult)
    ' You may not interact with the form and its contents
    ' from a different thread, and this callback procedure
    ' is all but guaranteed to be running from a different thread
    ' than the form. Therefore you cannot simply call code that 
    ' updates the UI.
    ' Instead, you must call the procedure from the form's thread.
    ' This code will use recursion to switch from the thread pool
    ' to the UI thread.
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        myStatus.addHistory("OnSalesReaderComplete - Background", "Sub")
        Dim switchThreads As New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.OnSalesReaderComplete)
        Dim args() As Object = {asynResult}
        Me.BeginInvoke(switchThreads, args)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' At this point, this code will run on the UI thread.
    Try
        myStatus.addHistory("OnSalesReaderComplete - UI", "Sub")
        Dim sourceText, rSalesId As String

        waitInProgressSales = False
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Sales:asynResult.IsCompleted1: {0}", asynResult.IsCompleted.ToString), "SqlNotificationRequest")
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Sales:asynResult.CompletedSynchronously: {0}", asynResult.CompletedSynchronously.ToString), "SqlNotificationRequest")
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = DirectCast(asynResult.AsyncState, SqlCommand).EndExecuteReader(asynResult)
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Sales:asynResult.IsCompleted2: {0}", asynResult.IsCompleted.ToString), "SqlNotificationRequest")
        Do While reader.Read
            ' Empty queue of messages.
            ' Application logic could parse
            ' the queue data to determine why things.
            'For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
            '    'Debug.WriteLine(reader(i).ToString())
            '    Console.WriteLine(reader(i).ToString)
            'Next

            Dim bytesQN As SqlBytes = reader.GetSqlBytes(reader.GetOrdinal("message_body"))
            Dim rdrXml As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(bytesQN.Stream)
            Do While rdrXml.Read
                Select Case rdrXml.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.Element
                        Select Case rdrXml.LocalName
                            Case "QueryNotification"
                                sourceText = rdrXml.GetAttribute("source")
                            Case "Message"
                                rSalesId = rdrXml.ReadElementContentAsString
                        End Select
                End Select
            Loop
        Loop

        reader.Close()


        ' The user can decide to request
        ' a new notification by
        ' checking the check box on the form.
        ' However, if the user has requested to 
        ' exit, we need to do that instead.
        If exitRequestedSales Then
            'Me.Close()
            commandSales.Notification = Nothing
        Else
            Select Case sourceText.ToLower
                Case "data"
                    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("SalesId: {0}, data notification", rSalesId), "SqlNotificationRequest")
                    Call GetSalesData(True, action.REATTACH)
                Case "timeout"
                    'check timeout is for this user and relates to current wait thread
                    Select Case salesId = rSalesId
                        Case True
                            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("SalesId: {0}, timeout - current", rSalesId), "SqlNotificationRequest")
                            Call GetSalesData(True, False)
                        Case False
                            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("SalesId: {0}, timeout - old", rSalesId), "SqlNotificationRequest")
                            Me.ListenSales()
                    End Select
            End Select
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call errorHandling(ex, "OnSalesReaderComplete", "Sub")
    End Try
End Sub
```

The problem seems to be where I am only refreshing the data and renewing the notification request (using GetSalesData) when either the notification is due to an update ("data") or the timeout is for the current request.  On other notifications, the application calls Me.ListenSales which creates a SQL command "WAITFOR (RECEIVE * FROM [QueueMessage])" and starts the callback listener as per the MSDN article.  If I remove the Me.ListenSales line, once a notification is received which is not due to data or the timeout of the current query, the application stops listening for notifications.

I have also posted the same question on MSDN forums (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/0f7a636d-0c9b-4b39-b341-6becf13873dc) as I have tried other resolutions without success so require some advice on whether this is possible and if so how.